# How do you read umlaut from user-given input for a Java application?

Tags: java, encoding, command-line

I wrote a command line program in Java that is supposed to take in a file name and process its contents, given certain requirements. It looks exactly like this when running:

```
These content types are required:
[Änderung, Adaptation, Content, Inhalte]

Please enter the name of a file
>> _
```

(See how the menu's umlaut is displayed correctly)
Now, the filenames might contain umlaute aswell. However, if entered, this is what happens:

```
These content types are required:
[Änderung, Adaptation, Content, Inhalte]

Please enter the name of a file
>> Über
<< [?ber] - Searching for the file
_
```

I've looked into encoding, but the first umlaut being displayed correctly makes me think there's something else going on. On the Java-side, I used a `BufferedReader` for String input.

I start the program via a .bat file like this:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -jar app.jar
PAUSE
```

I have to use the `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` here, so this can not be removed.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: I think the problem is with writing to the command window. On my PC Windows command windows use codepage 850 (open a command window and look at the properties in the menu. It shows the used codepage.) That means when you write you must use this encoding.

Comment: Wasnt this question asked yesterday?  I am fairly sure this is word for word the same questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that your problem is when your java code writes to the standard output stream.

I am in Israel and I managed to get my java code to write Hebrew characters to the [Windows] Command Prompt.

Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class StdoutHe {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String str = "\u05DD\u05D5\u05DC\u05E9";
        byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("Cp862");
        System.out.writeBytes(bytes);
    }
}
```

The code contains [unicode escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_(Unicode_block)) rather than literal Hebrew characters.

I use [charset] Cp862 because when I enter the command `CHCP` in the Command Prompt, the output I got was...

```
Active code page: 862
```

Then I used the [Supported Encodings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) from the JDK documentation to discover that the appropriate charset name is `Cp862`.

### EDIT

You aren't in Israel. Your computer probably does not have a font that can display Hebrew characters in a *Command Prompt* window. You need to make some changes to my code, above. You can't run it on your computer as is.

You need to change the following line (from the above code):

```java
String str = "\u05DD\u05D5\u05DC\u05E9";
```

Instead of the Hebrew unicode, enter an appropriate string, for example `Über`. In other words, replace the above line with...

```java
String str = "Über";
```

Then open a *Command Prompt* and enter the command `CHCP`.
Then lookup the appropriate java charset name that matches the output that you got for the `CHCP` command.
Then modify this line of code:

```java
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("Cp862");
```

and replace *Cp862* with the charset that matches the output your got when you ran the `CHCP` command.

Then run the code and see if it correctly prints **Über**.

### EDIT 2

So actually you need to configure the [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) that you use to get input from the user.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadsKbd {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.print("Enter: ");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in, "Cp862");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String input = br.readLine();
        System.out.printf("You entered: %s%n", input);
    }
}
```

Simply **replace** `"Cp862"` with the value that is relevant for your computer – which is, as I wrote earlier, the output of the [Windows] command CHCP. Then you can run the above code, as is. When you run it, enter a string containing an umlaut and it should be displayed correctly by the last line of the code.

Comment: I adapted this code to my needs, meaning:
- `str` is now user input, read in from a `BufferedReader`
- the charset I used was 1252 in order to print umlaute
This sadly has no effect, the problem persists, meaning I put in an umlaut and get out a `?`.

Comment: @TJ1232 does it work for you when `str` is **not** read from standard input stream and hard-coded as in the code in my answer?

Comment: Thank you, just saw your edit. See, the thing is this: Strings coming from Java are already displayed correctly. The program, as I tried to illustrate with the first code snippet in the question, can already display a menu with Umlaute (Änderung). The problem is the input. If I enter into CMD a text containing Umlaute, this is not being handed over to Java correctly. How could this be solved?